# PayPal Order Total and Item Total issues on ExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal

I have a working expressCheckout process, and all works well until i try to multiply the amounts by a given exchange rate.

Here are the 2 versions (1st, the working version with no exchange rate, 2nd the non working version with the implementation of the exchange rate:

Workign version

```
Imports PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.Model
```

Imports PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService
Imports PayPal.Manager

Partial Class paypalExpressCheckout
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim currentPreSale As New PreSale

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Session("ShoppingCartDT") Is Nothing Then

        currentPreSale = Session("currentPreSale")

        Dim request As New SetExpressCheckoutRequestType

        populateRequestObject(request)

        'Invoke the API
        Dim wrapper As New SetExpressCheckoutReq
        wrapper.SetExpressCheckoutRequest = request

        Dim service As New PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService

        Dim setECResponse As SetExpressCheckoutResponseType = service.SetExpressCheckout(wrapper)

        'Check for API return status
        Dim CurrContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

        CurrContext.Items.Add("paymentDetails", request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentDetails)

        setKeyResponseObjects(service, setECResponse)

    Else

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SetShippingAddress(ByRef shippingAddress As AddressType)

    Dim selectedCountry As New Country
    Dim currentUser As User = Session("currentUser")

    selectedCountry.GetCountryDetails(currentPreSale.DeliveryCountryId.ToString())

    shippingAddress.Name = currentUser.FirstName & " " & currentUser.LastName
    shippingAddress.Street1 = currentPreSale.DeliveryAddress
    shippingAddress.Street2 = ""
    shippingAddress.CityName = ""
    shippingAddress.StateOrProvince = ""
    shippingAddress.Country = [Enum].Parse(GetType(CountryCodeType), selectedCountry.CountryCode)
    shippingAddress.Phone = currentUser.Phone & ""
    shippingAddress.PostalCode = ""

End Sub

Private Sub populateRequestObject(ByRef request As SetExpressCheckoutRequestType)

    Dim deliveryAddress As New Address
    Dim currentUser As User = Session("currentUser")
    Dim selectedCurrency As New Currency

    selectedCurrency.GetCurrencyDetails(currentPreSale.CurrencyId.ToString())

    'Dim userDetails As New UserDetails
    Dim currency As CurrencyCodeType = selectedCurrency.PayPalCurrencyCode
    Dim ecDetails As New SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType
    Dim paymentDetails As New PaymentDetailsType
    Dim orderTotal As Double = 0
    Dim itemTotal As Double = 0
    Dim shippingValue As Double = currentPreSale.ShippingTotal
    Dim HandlingTotal As Double = 0
    Dim TaxTotal As Double = 0
    Dim shipAddress As New AddressType
    Dim dataTableCarrinho As DataTable
    Dim dataRowCarrinho As DataRow


    If currentPreSale.ShippingTotal > 0 Then

        SetShippingAddress(shipAddress)

    End If

    'userDetails.Get_ItemDetails(Session("userId").ToString())

    ecDetails.ReturnURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("appURL") & "doExpressCheckoutPayment.aspx"
    ecDetails.CancelURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("appCurrentServer") & Page.GetRouteUrl("paypalCancel" & UCase(Left(Session("language"), 2)), New With {.lang = Left(Session("language"), 2)})
    ecDetails.BuyerEmail = currentUser.Email
    ecDetails.ReqConfirmShipping = 0
    ecDetails.AddressOverride = 0
    If CDec(currentPreSale.ShippingTotal) > 0 Then
        ecDetails.NoShipping = 0
    Else
        ecDetails.NoShipping = 1
    End If

    'Payment Details
    If (shippingValue > 0) Then
        paymentDetails.ShippingTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, currentPreSale.ShippingTotal)
    End If

    paymentDetails.OrderDescription = "KTB Order"
    paymentDetails.PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.SALE

    orderTotal += shippingValue

    'Lista de Items - GUY preencher
    dataTableCarrinho = Session("ShoppingCartDT")

    For Each dataRowCarrinho In dataTableCarrinho.Rows

        Dim currentProduct As New Product

        currentProduct.GetProductDetails(dataRowCarrinho("ProductId").ToString(), Session("LanguageId").ToString())

        Dim itemDetails As New PaymentDetailsItemType
        itemDetails.Name = currentProduct.Title
        'itemDetails.Amount = New BasicAmountType(currency, dataRowCarrinho("Price").ToString())
        itemDetails.Amount = New BasicAmountType(currency, CDec(dataRowCarrinho("Price")))
        itemDetails.Quantity = CInt(dataRowCarrinho("Quantity"))
        itemDetails.Tax = New BasicAmountType(currency, 0)
        itemDetails.Description = ""
        itemDetails.ItemCategory = ItemCategoryType.PHYSICAL

        paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem.Add(itemDetails)

        orderTotal += CDec(dataRowCarrinho("Price")) * CInt(dataRowCarrinho("Quantity"))
        itemTotal += CDec(dataRowCarrinho("Price")) * CInt(dataRowCarrinho("Quantity"))


    Next

    'ExceptionUtility.LogInfo("orderTotal = " & orderTotal)
    'ExceptionUtility.LogInfo("itemTotal = " & itemTotal)
    'ExceptionUtility.LogInfo("shippingTotal = " & (currentPreSale.ShippingTotal * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate))

    'paymentDetails.ItemTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, CDec(currentPreSale.ProductTotal * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate))
    'paymentDetails.OrderTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, CDec((currentPreSale.ProductTotal + currentPreSale.ShippingTotal) * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate))
    paymentDetails.ItemTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, itemTotal)
    paymentDetails.OrderTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, orderTotal)

    ecDetails.PaymentDetails.Add(paymentDetails)
    ecDetails.PaymentDetails(0).ShipToAddress = shipAddress

    request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = ecDetails

End Sub

Private Sub setKeyResponseObjects(ByVal service As PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService, ByVal setECResponse As SetExpressCheckoutResponseType)

    Dim keyResponseParameters As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    keyResponseParameters.Add("API Status", setECResponse.Ack.ToString())

    Dim CurrContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

    If (setECResponse.Ack.Equals(AckCodeType.FAILURE) Or ((Not IsNothing(setECResponse.Errors)) And setECResponse.Errors.Count > 0)) Then

        ExceptionUtility.LogInfo(setECResponse.Errors.Item(0).LongMessage)

        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_error", setECResponse.Errors)
        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_redirectURL", Nothing)
    Else
        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_error", Nothing)
        keyResponseParameters.Add("EC token", setECResponse.Token)

        Dim paypalUrl As String = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperty("paypalUrl").ToString()

        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_redirectURL", paypalUrl + "_express-checkout&token=" + setECResponse.Token)
    End If

    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_keyResponseObject", keyResponseParameters)
    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_apiName", "SetExpressCheckout")
    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_requestPayload", service.getLastRequest())
    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_responsePayload", service.getLastResponse())

    Response.Redirect(CurrContext.Items.Item("Response_redirectURL"))
    'Server.Transfer("APIResponse.aspx")

    Dim a As String = ""
End Sub
```

End Class

Non Working version

```
Imports PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.Model
```

Imports PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService
Imports PayPal.Manager

Partial Class paypalExpressCheckout
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim currentPreSale As New PreSale

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Session("ShoppingCartDT") Is Nothing Then

        currentPreSale = Session("currentPreSale")

        Dim request As New SetExpressCheckoutRequestType

        populateRequestObject(request)

        'Invoke the API
        Dim wrapper As New SetExpressCheckoutReq
        wrapper.SetExpressCheckoutRequest = request

        Dim service As New PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService

        Dim setECResponse As SetExpressCheckoutResponseType = service.SetExpressCheckout(wrapper)

        'Check for API return status
        Dim CurrContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

        CurrContext.Items.Add("paymentDetails", request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentDetails)

        setKeyResponseObjects(service, setECResponse)

    Else

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SetShippingAddress(ByRef shippingAddress As AddressType)

    Dim selectedCountry As New Country
    Dim currentUser As User = Session("currentUser")

    selectedCountry.GetCountryDetails(currentPreSale.DeliveryCountryId.ToString())

    shippingAddress.Name = currentUser.FirstName & " " & currentUser.LastName
    shippingAddress.Street1 = currentPreSale.DeliveryAddress
    shippingAddress.Street2 = ""
    shippingAddress.CityName = ""
    shippingAddress.StateOrProvince = ""
    shippingAddress.Country = [Enum].Parse(GetType(CountryCodeType), selectedCountry.CountryCode)
    shippingAddress.Phone = currentUser.Phone & ""
    shippingAddress.PostalCode = ""

End Sub

Private Sub populateRequestObject(ByRef request As SetExpressCheckoutRequestType)

    Dim deliveryAddress As New Address
    Dim currentUser As User = Session("currentUser")
    Dim selectedCurrency As New Currency

    selectedCurrency.GetCurrencyDetails(currentPreSale.CurrencyId.ToString())

    'Dim userDetails As New UserDetails
    Dim currency As CurrencyCodeType = selectedCurrency.PayPalCurrencyCode
    Dim ecDetails As New SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType
    Dim paymentDetails As New PaymentDetailsType
    Dim orderTotal As Double = 0
    Dim itemTotal As Double = 0
    Dim shippingValue As Double = currentPreSale.ShippingTotal
    Dim HandlingTotal As Double = 0
    Dim TaxTotal As Double = 0
    Dim shipAddress As New AddressType
    Dim dataTableCarrinho As DataTable
    Dim dataRowCarrinho As DataRow


    If currentPreSale.ShippingTotal > 0 Then

        SetShippingAddress(shipAddress)

    End If

    'userDetails.Get_ItemDetails(Session("userId").ToString())

    ecDetails.ReturnURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("appURL") & "doExpressCheckoutPayment.aspx"
    ecDetails.CancelURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("appCurrentServer") & Page.GetRouteUrl("paypalCancel" & UCase(Left(Session("language"), 2)), New With {.lang = Left(Session("language"), 2)})
    ecDetails.BuyerEmail = currentUser.Email
    ecDetails.ReqConfirmShipping = 0
    ecDetails.AddressOverride = 0
    If CDec(currentPreSale.ShippingTotal) > 0 Then
        ecDetails.NoShipping = 0
    Else
        ecDetails.NoShipping = 1
    End If

    'Payment Details
    If (shippingValue > 0) Then
        paymentDetails.ShippingTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, currentPreSale.ShippingTotal * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate)
    End If

    paymentDetails.OrderDescription = "KTB Order"
    paymentDetails.PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.SALE

    orderTotal += shippingValue * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate

    'Lista de Items - GUY preencher
    dataTableCarrinho = Session("ShoppingCartDT")

    For Each dataRowCarrinho In dataTableCarrinho.Rows

        Dim currentProduct As New Product

        currentProduct.GetProductDetails(dataRowCarrinho("ProductId").ToString(), Session("LanguageId").ToString())

        Dim itemDetails As New PaymentDetailsItemType
        itemDetails.Name = currentProduct.Title
        'itemDetails.Amount = New BasicAmountType(currency, dataRowCarrinho("Price").ToString())
        itemDetails.Amount = New BasicAmountType(currency, CDec(dataRowCarrinho("Price") * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate))
        itemDetails.Quantity = CInt(dataRowCarrinho("Quantity"))
        itemDetails.Tax = New BasicAmountType(currency, 0)
        itemDetails.Description = ""
        itemDetails.ItemCategory = ItemCategoryType.PHYSICAL

        paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem.Add(itemDetails)

        orderTotal += CDec(dataRowCarrinho("Price")) * CInt(dataRowCarrinho("Quantity") * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate)
        itemTotal += CDec(dataRowCarrinho("Price")) * CInt(dataRowCarrinho("Quantity") * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate)


    Next

    'ExceptionUtility.LogInfo("orderTotal = " & orderTotal)
    'ExceptionUtility.LogInfo("itemTotal = " & itemTotal)
    'ExceptionUtility.LogInfo("shippingTotal = " & (currentPreSale.ShippingTotal * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate))

    'paymentDetails.ItemTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, CDec(currentPreSale.ProductTotal * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate))
    'paymentDetails.OrderTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, CDec((currentPreSale.ProductTotal + currentPreSale.ShippingTotal) * currentPreSale.ExchangeRate))
    paymentDetails.ItemTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, itemTotal)
    paymentDetails.OrderTotal = New BasicAmountType(currency, orderTotal)

    ecDetails.PaymentDetails.Add(paymentDetails)
    ecDetails.PaymentDetails(0).ShipToAddress = shipAddress

    request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = ecDetails

End Sub

Private Sub setKeyResponseObjects(ByVal service As PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService, ByVal setECResponse As SetExpressCheckoutResponseType)

    Dim keyResponseParameters As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    keyResponseParameters.Add("API Status", setECResponse.Ack.ToString())

    Dim CurrContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

    If (setECResponse.Ack.Equals(AckCodeType.FAILURE) Or ((Not IsNothing(setECResponse.Errors)) And setECResponse.Errors.Count > 0)) Then

        ExceptionUtility.LogInfo(setECResponse.Errors.Item(0).LongMessage)

        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_error", setECResponse.Errors)
        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_redirectURL", Nothing)
    Else
        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_error", Nothing)
        keyResponseParameters.Add("EC token", setECResponse.Token)

        Dim paypalUrl As String = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperty("paypalUrl").ToString()

        CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_redirectURL", paypalUrl + "_express-checkout&token=" + setECResponse.Token)
    End If

    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_keyResponseObject", keyResponseParameters)
    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_apiName", "SetExpressCheckout")
    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_requestPayload", service.getLastRequest())
    CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_responsePayload", service.getLastResponse())

    Response.Redirect(CurrContext.Items.Item("Response_redirectURL"))
    'Server.Transfer("APIResponse.aspx")

    Dim a As String = ""
End Sub
```

End Class

it keeps throwing me the following error:

Item amount is invalid.

Anyone got any clue on what is happeing and how to solve it?

Thx

Comment: Need to see the actual request getting generated and sent to PayPal.

Comment: How can i provide you that?

Comment: Your code is generating it.  Need to see the final result instead of the code that is generating the request.